# Eclipse CDT has DEBUG defined in Release build

Tags: c++, debugging, cygwin, eclipse-cdt, windows-7-x64

I'm using Eclipse CDT to write some C++ code (on Win7 with Cygwin). I naturally want different/additional behavior when debugging, and use `#ifdef DEBUG` occasionally. Unfortunately, it seems that I somehow have `DEBUG` defined in Release build configuration as well.

How can I get Eclipse CDT to not define DEBUG?

Comment: Try Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings. Select the Release configuration, go to the Tool Settings tab and under GCC C++ Compiler there is a Preprocessor section which includes the defined symbols.

Comment: @BlackBear: Couldn't find anything there... but I might do an #undef using that list.

Answer (score 1):

```
#undef DEBUG
```

that directive will undefine things.

edit: I'm aware you probably just want this for a specific IDE that's adding the define outside of the source files, finding that option in IDE settings is a better way to go about it, but this will also work if it's in a header which is included by all project files.